# How to represent mutually exclusive events in CSP

Tags: computation-models, parallel-computing

I am studying Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP), and I understand that an event can be "emmited" ($\overline{e}$) and an event can be "waited on" ($e$), so that an event will sync with another parallel event ($\overline{e} || a \rightarrow e$).

Now how do I represent the fact that an event *must* not occur at the same time as another one, but can occur right after or right before? Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have asked this question at my university, and the answer I got was:

1. The model does not account for parallelism, only concurrency.
2. The model assumes that events are "instant" or "atomic".

So no two events can occur at the same time because no two things ever happen at the same time (no "paralellism"), and the event takes no "time", of which there is no concept of.